# C# protofile type referenced twice for enum

Tags: c#, protocol-buffers

I saw this link [Use enums from external class to avoid define in .proto?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/13753174/use-enums-from-external-class-to-avoid-define-in-proto) but it doesnt help me much

So my idea is to have common proto enums, which can be used in requests and responses for the single microservice in the different methods

I define enum like this

```
syntax = "proto3";

option csharp_namespace = "MyNamespace.Enums";

package MyPackage;

enum StatusResponseEnum{
    Unknown = 0;
    Success = 1;
    Failed = 2;
}
```

I don't use enums in the service proto, just in requests or responses, like this

```
syntax = "proto3";

option csharp_namespace = "MyNamespace.Requests";

import "Enums/StatusResponseEnum.proto";

package MyPackage;

// The request message
message MyMessage{
    int32 TransactionId = 1;
    StatusResponseEnum Status = 2;
}
```

And in the microservice (DDD principle) i have such warning or error

```
Error CS0433  The type 'StatusResponseEnum' exists in both 'Application, Version=1.0.0.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=null' and 'Nuget.Package.Proto.Shared, Version=1.0.0.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=null'
```

I have Application project in the Visual Studio solution where my proto service file referenced
And i have own nuget package where are all the protos

PS Strange thing, this problem doesn't appears if i use standalone class for decimal, like this one

```
syntax = "proto3";

option csharp_namespace = "Nuget.Package.Proto.CustomTypes";

//Name "DecimalValue" prevents conflict with C# Decimal type
message DecimalValue {

  //The whole units of the amount.
  int64 units = 1;

  /*Number of nano (10^-9) units of the amount.
  The value must be between -999,999,999 and +999,999,999 inclusive.
  If `units` is positive, `nanos` must be positive or zero.
  If `units` is zero, `nanos` can be positive, zero, or negative.
  If `units` is negative, `nanos` must be negative or zero.
  For example $-1.75 is represented as `units`=-1 and `nanos`=-750,000,000. */

  int32 nanos = 2;
}
```

Comment: The error kind of says it, there are two definitions of `StatusResponseEnum`. You probably need to qualify it better in the places you use it (to remove any ambiguities). Try renaming your proto enum to something else and see if the error is still happening.

Comment: It seems the problem was with namespaces. I set unique namespace for all the enums and removed package MyPackage;